# Send axios request when leaving the page

Tags: javascript, axios, dom-events

I want to send a http request using axios when the document `pagehide` event happens, I wonder if it is possible to know the axios is successfully sent out since the request is asynchronous? Or is there any way to make the request synchronous? I write sample code below.

```
document.addEventListener("pagehide", function () {
    sendRequest();
})

sendRequest() {
    axios.get('/targetUrl', params).then();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it at some to some extent... I use `sendBeacon` when possible, and for some browsers which not support the beacon API, I use synchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a "Ok" response (status code 200) which will indicate you that the request was sent successfully.

I am not sure about synchronous request but you can just use:

```
axios.get('/targetUrl', params);
```

This will send the signal you want to. If you'd like to wait for the response then you can use promises. In case the server returns a 4xx code response, axios will throw an error, you can use axios inside a try-catch block to handle if there is an error.

```
async function sendRequest() {
    try {
await axios.get('/targetUrl', params);
}
catch (Error)
{
if(Error.IsAxios) // This will return true if error is due to axios
{
alert('Request was not successful');
}
else
{
console.error(Error.toString());
}
}    
}
```

Comment: This will not fire when leaving the page (onpagehide event) on most/all browsers.